# Nginx redirect to another page if url contain specific query string

Tags: regex, nginx, redirect, nginx-location

I want to redirect all URLs to another page if the URL contains a query string starting with fl=&fl=

incoming URL's can be anything starting with the query sting fl=&fl=

https://example.com/a-core/?fl=&fl=test&fl=test1&fl=xyz;&fl=test3&fl=test4&fl=test5

https://example.com/a-core/?fl=&fl=test&fl=test0&fl=cpl;&fl=test8&fl=test9&fl=test7

all of the above URLs are starting with query string fl=&fl= and need to be redirected to example2.com/test123

I have tried this but didn't work

```
if ($args = "fl=&fl=*") {
  return 301 https://example2.com/test123;
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The `=` operator does not understand wildcards such as `*`. You will need to use *regular expression* syntax.

For example:

```
if ($args ~* "^fl=&fl=") { ... }
```

See [this document](http://nginx.org/en/docs/http/ngx_http_rewrite_module.html#if) for details.